# Why Does Entire TCP/UDP Packet Get Retransmitted Instead of Just Missing Data

Tags: networking, tcp, udp, router, packet

So, this may be a dumb question, but to my understanding if I am sending data via TCP or UDP, if any one of the IP packets that make up that TCP/UDP packet get dropped, the entire TCP/UDP packet is retransmitted, but my question is why can't we just send the parts of the data that are missing. Currently, my only reasoning for this is because if we were to send a ACK for each IP packet that got received that would add to network congestion. Is this correct or are there other reasons we have to resend all the data in a TCP/UDP packet when only a single or a few IP packets are dropped?

Comment: TCP will request the missing data, but UDP does not do anything of the sort. The ACK is not for the IP packet, because IP, like UDP is connectionless. The ACK is for the TCP segment. TCP knows if a segment is missing, but UDP has no idea if a datagram goes missing, and it does not ACK data. It is up to the application using UDP to determine if data are missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IP fragmentation and reassembly happen transparently to upper layers: upper layers aren't aware of that. Also, the transport for TCP is not necessarily IP.

TCP stack tracks the dispatch and retransmission of TCP segments. Each TCP segment has a sequence number. TCP stack tracks the TCP sequence numbers and can only retransmit the entire TCP segment.

Should a TCP segment get fragmented into multiple IP datagrams, TCP stack is not aware of that and fragmentation may happen on intermediate hops. Normally, though, TCP segment fragmentation doesn't happen because TCP obeys [MTU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_transmission_unit)/MSS specifically to avoid TCP segment [fragmentation on IP level](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_fragmentation).

Comment: ok i think i get your answer. is this right?

to my understanding TCP segments will only get fragmented into IP datagrams due to IP fragmentation, in which case the fact that a particular IP datagram is dropped is completely transparent to the TCP layer. However, TCP obeys MTU/MSS and so may choose to split data into multiple TCP packets, at which point it is able to resend that partial packet, since it is known to TCP. In that case my only question is why the IP layer doesn't, supposing IP fragmentation into say 2 IP packets, retransmit 1 of those fragments if 1 drops.

Comment: @user2776326 TCP stack fragments user data into TCP segments and sends/receives complete TCP segments. TCP cannot send or receive a part of a TCP segment. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol#TCP_segment_structure

Comment: I guess the reason is you might just not care in say something like UDP if the packet actually arrived or not, so if 1 segment fails you can't rely on the IP level to ask for a retransmission since in protocols that do not guarantee data delivery, implementing such a thing in the IP level would be wasteful.